# How to remove an observer for NSNotification in a UIView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, nsnotifications

I've added an observer in a custom UIView I've created under `initWithFrame:`.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
         selector:@selector(updateZipFromLocation:) 
          name:@"zipFoundFromLocation" 
           object:nil];
```

The problem is, this view is a subview.  When the view is loaded again, it calls the initWithFrame message again, thus adding two observers and so on.  How can I remove the observer when the view is going to disappear?  Since it is a `UIView`, it says that `viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated` is not a valid method.  Any ideas?

Comment: Just a heads-up, KVO refers to key-value observing, which is a different concept from `NSNotificationCenter`.

Comment: Oops, still a little new to all of this. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You've said that `initWithFrame:` is being called more than once, so I assume this means that the view is being destroyed and recreated. You can remove the view as an observer in `dealloc`, which will be called when the view is no longer retained by anyone:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: The problem is, dealloc is never called.  I've put NSLog statements there and all.  Maybe I need to remove the subview in my superview and then dealloc will be called.

Comment: @sudo rm -rf If `dealloc` isn't being called, but `initWithFrame:` is being called more than once, it sounds like you have a memory leak. Make sure you're releasing the subviews as soon as you no longer need them (immediately after `addSubview:` is usually appropriate).

Comment: I have my subview created as an instance variable so I can access it in other methods.  How should I deal with it then?  Releasing it crashes my app.

Comment: @sudo rm -rf `addSubview:` will retain the subview for as long as the parent view is still around, so you can safely release the view you added immediately afterward. If you still need a reference to it, you can keep it around until it's removed from the superview or until `viewDidUnload` is called (at which point you should just set it to `nil`). If its lifecycle doesn't coincide with your view controller's, then it would be appropriate to retain and release it on a more granular level.

Comment: Ah, I just fixed it.  I forgot to remove the observer so it was trying to run a method on a non-existant view.  Thank you for your help!  I'll accept it as answer as soon as it's available.